# Can't go between fragments onClick

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, FragmentA and FragmentB. I have a button on the layout of FragmentA, I want to go to FragmentB when I click that button. I tried a few things but it doesn't work. This is what I have.

This is FragmentA.

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        button= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.clickMe);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.activity_main, fragment, fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This is FragmentB.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        textView= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

This is fragment_a.xml with the button inside it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="net.cairobus.communication.FragmentA">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/clickMe"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I can't figure out why it won't work

Answer (score 0):

`button.setOnClickListener(this);`

Put this below

```
button= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.clickMe);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `replace` expects an id not a layout.

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Normally, you would have a layout for your activity, with some other child layout for your fragments (for instance, a RelativeLayout).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Other stuff -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

    <!-- Other stuff -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then on your replace:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.toString());
```

Comment: I created a RelativeLayout in my "activity_main" with the id "FragmentContainer" and I put my fragment in it. I put the id of the container instead of the layout in the replace(). But it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be several things: is your activity putting your FragmentA ? I mean, just leaving the container empty and populating it from your activity.
Try to make the replace on your activity instead of doing it from your Fargment